# error when display panel in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I had windows form I did my code to display panel where condition but this error apeared (object refrencer.....) on panel1.Show();

```
public partial class Checker : Form
{
    public Checker()
    {
        RegistryKey adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Adobe");
        if (adobe == null)
        {
            panel1.Show(); 
        }
    }

    private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you don't have an instance of your panel1.
Where is it declared? Is it a panel on a form somewhere? If so, where is your form declared?

If the code above is your form, you might want to call

```
InitializeComponent();
```

before you continue your constructor.